# How to position text to be on the top edge of its container div?

Tags: css, sass, less

[image]

Here the Lorem ipsum text i want to achieve.

I tried it with setting the container div to position relative and the text container to position absolut and move it with top: negative value, but it seems not doing what i want.

Comment: please add some code around this.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a negative top margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;   
}
h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
</div>
```